# how to solve git push have error?updated the branch through the commit in live

Tags: git

**I changed my git REDME file update . later my changes added the local .then commit have  pushing to git having error.**

```
* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Comment: With git pull --ff-only, Git will update your branch only if it can be “fast-forwarded” without creating new commits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+You+have+divergent+branches+and+need+to+specify+how+to+reconcile+them

Answer (score -1):

i Found an solution for an my question

i just done my terminal window this commands

my problem is solved

1 git fetch

2 git rebase origin/main